# Running silent install with iss response file

Tags: c#, file, process, console

I need to run a cmd command that silently install a software with a response file, but I can't find the correct syntax and keep having a "the specified path could not be found" error

I tried to run it without the /s and /f1 parameters, and it worked. I can also successfully launch both files, so it doesn't come from their path.
I also tried to put the exe and iss files in the program folder to get rid of the relative paths, but I still have the same error...

```cs
string command = "\"\"Executable Folder Path\\setup.exe\"\" /s /f1\"\"Config Path\\conf_file.iss\"\"";
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    process.Start();

    process.WaitForExit();

   string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax please ?

Comment: These parameters are specific to `setup.exe`. We couldn't possibly know what they are. If you can run the exe from command line then this is just a matter of porting the invocation to c#. Btw, you don't need to run `cmd /c` in c#.

Comment: No, they are always the same for every software you want to install silently with an iss file : http://www.silentinstall.org/InstallShield
The /s is for install silently, and the /f1 parameter is to use a configuration file

You mean I can simply write my commands with a Console.WriteLine() ?

Answer (score 0):

This should get your process started:

```
var setupExe = "Full/Path/To/setup.exe";
var configIss = "Full/Path/To/config.iss";
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(setupExe);
procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(setupExe);
procStartInfo.Arguments = $"/s /f1\"{configIss}\"";
```